# Using "while read" causes ambiguous redirect

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, while-loop

i have this very simple script:

```
data=$(<data.txt)
counter=10

#just a dbquery using $data
result=(`psql -X -t -AF $'\t' -h $POSTGRES_HOST -d $POSTGRES_DATABASE -U $POSTGRES_USERNAME  -w -c "select COUNT(field_value) from table where field_value in ($data)"`)

if [ $result == counter ]; then
    echo -e "\e[92m Success \e[39m"
  else
    while read -r dataLine;
      do
        result=(`psql -X -t -AF $'\t' -h $POSTGRES_HOST -d $POSTGRES_DATABASE -U $POSTGRES_USERNAME  -w -c "select field_value from fields where field_value = $dataLine" `)
        if [ -z "$result" ]; then
          echo "$dataLine failed"
        fi
      done < $data
fi
```

I am getting `line 17: $data: ambiguous redirect` (where `fi` is) i imagine the issue is something with the first line reading data.txt then later referencing $data on the read -r but im not exactly sure what is wrong.

Any ideas?

edit: error in line 17, not 21.

edit2: fixed "results" typo inside the loop.

edit3: `data.txt` contains a list of UUIDs:

```
'5dce6dcc-5368-4dc2-b26e-01b92c3dd3aa',
'6dab9b13-1734-4766-93f5-a96d0e0afd38',
'c365e709-296b-4e8e-acf9-1d9e252325f6'
```

Comment: What does `data.txt` contain? `<` must be followed by a single filename.

Comment: `if [ result == counter ]` should be `if [ $result == $counter ]` you're missing the `$`.

Comment: I suspect you actually want `done < data.txt`.

Comment: Why are you putting `()` around your `psql` calls? That puts the results in an array, is that what you want?

Comment: Inside the loop you set the variable `results` (plural) but then use `$result` (singular) in the `if` statement.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the code presented yields the error message specified, inasmuch as the message refers to line 21, and there are fewer than 21 lines altogether in the script.  What message do you get from the code you've actually posted?

Comment: 1. data.txt contains a list of UUIDS
2. thanks, added $results but didnt solve the ambiguous error
3. the psql query is fine, the issue is the ambiguous error
4. results was a typo cleaning up sensitive data, the code is an exact copy now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<` redirection takes a filename, but you are passing it string data.

To redirect from a string, use a `<<<` here-string instead:

```
data=$(< data.txt)
cat <<< "$data"
```

Or if you are using `sh` instead of `bash`, use a short here-doc:

```
cat << end
$data
end
```

Though it would be better to just read directly from the file, since this allows you to stream arbitrary amounts of data without reading it into memory first:

```
data="data.txt"
cat < "$data"
```

---

While not applicable to this question, but for the benefit of future readers, you also get this error if you try to redirect from a file with spaces in the name:

```
$ file="my file.txt"
$ cat < $file
bash: $file: ambiguous redirect
```

In this case you simply have to quote the variable:

```
$ cat < "$file"
My file contents
```

Comment: Thanks! As Barmar also suggested on the comments, it also works if you replace done < $data with done < data.txt